# Isolating a variable that appears twice

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stumped:  I have an equation $e - 1 = -2\left(\frac{f}{f+1}\right)$; I need to isolate f so that I can solve for it when $e$ is known, and try as I might, I can't figure out how to rearrange the equation.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Treat $e-1$ as a single number, and since we don't like fractions, multiply both sides by $f+1$.  That should make it a little easier.

Comment: Solving a linear equation such as this has four basic steps: Simplify, sort, factor, divide. Simplify by clearing fractions from the equation (careful of extraneous solutions) removing parentheses and combining like terms which are on the same side of the equation. Sort by moving all terms containing the variable for which you are solving to one side and all other terms to the other side. Then factor out the variable from the terms containing it. Finally divide the term containing the variable by its coefficient to obtain the solution. Note that $f$ cannot equal $-1$.

Comment: $\frac{f}{f+1}=1-\frac{1}{f+1}$, then $f$ only appears once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is:
$e-1=-2\left(\frac{f}{f+1}\right)$
where e is an unknown and not the exponential function (exp). Then the solution can be found as follows:

1. multiply both sides by the denominator of the right hand side:
   $$(e-1)(f+1)=-2f$$
2. expand the bracket on the left hand side:
   $$ ef-f+e-1 = -2f$$
3. Collect like terms:
   $$ef-f+2f=1-e$$
   $$ef +f=1-e$$ $$f(1+e)=1-e$$
4. divide both sides by the coefficient of $f$ and you have the answer:
   $$f=\frac{1-e}{1+e}$$

Comment: Okay, it was the second step in part 3 where I was messing up...I kept getting that far, but when I couldn't get to the right answer from that point, I assumed I had been wrong UP TO that point.

THANKS!